# Vs2017: NuGet packages not restored with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

1. I build from VS2017 and the packages are downloaded and the projects
   build.
2. Then I nuke the packages folder.
3. Then I build using MSBuild the projects fail because the packages don't
   exist, they haven't been restored.

I have "download missing packages" on
[image]

The project files would have been originally created in VS 2013

The build.proj using the MSBuild task to build the solution.

```
<MSBuild Projects ="$(root)\src\MySolution.sln" ContinueOnError ="false" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
    <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
</MSBuild>
```

My google-fu has failed me, any and all ideas will be greatfully received.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`packages.config` based projects need to be restored via NuGet, not MSBuild. Visual Studio does this when requesting a build via VS. If you need to do it from command line, you need to use the command line `nuget.exe` utility to restore the packages.

Only the `PackageReference` way of referencing NuGet packages is integrated into MSBuild. You can switch to this format by uninstalling all NuGet packages from the project, and changing the default package management format or select the "Allow format selection on first package install" checkbox. Then you can re-add the packages (only top-level packages are needed) and make sure it does not generate a `packages.config` file.

There's a few issues here:

1. After a restore, MSBuild has to re-evaluate the project file. When using the `<MSBuild>` task inside a CI script, this only happens when a different set of properties are passed to the task. This is because the Restore generates auto-imported files in the `obj\` directory that are checked for during the evaluation.
2. Should the restore not generate, but alter these files, this is not enough and the project has to be re-evaluated with clean xml caches. This is not possible with the `<MSBuild>` task. MSBuild 15.5 has introduces a `/restore` option to execute a `Restore` target, then clean these caches (for which there was no API before) and execute the rest of the build as requested. Before 15.5, two separate invocations of `msbuild.exe` were needed to ensure that incremental restore+builds produce the correct output.

If you want to use a CI build project with `PackageReference`, the safest way is to create a `build.proj` that has a restore and a build target:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Restore">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(root)\src\MySolution.sln" Targets="Restore" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(root)\src\MySolution.sln" Targets="Build" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And execute it using

```
msbuild /restore /t:Build build.proj
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that calling `nuget restore MySolution.sln` will restore the packages for a solution.

I put `nuget.exe` in my build folder, and run restore for each solution in my source tree.

My MsBuild target to restore packages for all projects in all solutions.

```
<Target Name="NuGetRestore">
  <ItemGroup>
    <slns Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\**\*.sln"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\nuget restore %(slns.Identity)"/>
</Target>
```

`Nuget.exe` doesn't have to be in each project folder, just in the folder with build.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the issue of MSBuild not pulling the packages.  I added the path `nuget.config` file using [`RestoreConfigFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets) to the properties parameter

```
RestoreConfigFile=$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)\.nuget\nuget.config
```

and also changed the Targets value on the MSBuild task:

```
MSBuild Targets="Restore;Clean;Build" Projects=...
```

The [`Restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#restore-target) target actually forced the pulling of the packages and the `RestoreConfigFile` pointed it to my settings.

Comment: Never run restore and other targets inside the same invocation. Use two different `<MSBuild>` tasks with different properties to cause re-evaluation or create a restore target in the ci build project and call it using `msbuild.exe /restore` (msbuild 15.5 feature). But I think the OP has problems with packages.config based projects which is not handled by the `Restore` target at the moment.